# VirtualizingStackPanel + MVVM + multiple selection

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm, stackpanel, virtualizingstackpanel

I have implemented a selection pattern similar to the one described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803216/managing-multiple-selections-with-mvvm) using a ViewModel to store the IsSelected value, and by binding the `ListViewItem.IsSelected` to the ViewModel IsSelected:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=IsSelected}"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

It works in general, but I encounter a severe problem.  By using the a `VirtualizingStackPanel` as the panel in the list view, only the visible `ListViewItem` are getting created.  If I use "Ctrl+A" to select all items, or by using shortcut combination such "Shift+Ctrl+End" on the first item, all items get selected, but for the non visible items, the ViewModel does not get its IsSelected set to true.  That is logical, because if the `ListViewItem` are not created, the binding can't work.

Anybody experienced the same issue, and found a solution (apart from not using a `VirtualizingStackPanel`)?

Comment: Try this complete solution for this issue:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/29545790

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I found another way of handling selection in the MVVM pattern, which solved my issue.  Instead of maintaining the selection in the viewmodel, the selection is retrieved from the ListView/ListBox, and passed as a parameter to the Command. All done in XAML:

```
<ListView 
    x:Name="_items"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" ... />

<Button 
    Content="Remove Selected" 
    Command="{Binding RemoveSelectedItemsCommand}" 
    CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=_items, Path=SelectedItems}"/>
```

in my ViewModel:

```
private void RemoveSelection(object parameter)
{
    IList selection = (IList)parameter;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, but you cannot select items programmatically from the viewmodel this way.

Comment: It will aslo won't work if Listview and the button are in different user control scope.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I ended up solving this by deriving a ListBoxEx class from ListBox, and adding code to respond to selection changes, enforcing the selection state on the item view models:

```
private readonly List<IListItemViewModelBase> selectedItems = new List<IListItemViewModelBase>();

protected override void OnSelectionChanged(SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnSelectionChanged(e);

    bool isVirtualizing = VirtualizingStackPanel.GetIsVirtualizing(this);
    bool isMultiSelect = (SelectionMode != SelectionMode.Single);

    if (isVirtualizing && isMultiSelect)
    {
        var newSelectedItems = SelectedItems.Cast<IListItemViewModelBase>();

        foreach (var deselectedItem in this.selectedItems.Except(newSelectedItems))
        {
            deselectedItem.IsSelected = false;
        }

        this.selectedItems.Clear();
        this.selectedItems.AddRange(newSelectedItems);

        foreach (var newlySelectedItem in this.selectedItems)
        {
            newlySelectedItem.IsSelected = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Solves the root problem by keeping the viewmodel in sync!

Comment: Finally, a fix to virtualisation/MVVM/IsSelected issues that have bugged me for years!

Answer (score 1):

Apart from not using `VirtualizingStackPanel`, the only thing I can think of is to capture those keyboard shortcuts and have methods for modifying a certain range of your `ViewModel` items so that their `IsSelected` property is set to `True` (e.g., `SelectAll()`, `SelectFromCurrentToEnd()`). Basically bypassing the `Binding` on `ListViewItem` for controlling the selection for such cases.

Comment: Don't forget all the different ways this can happen with the keyboard or mouse! Ctrl+A, Shift+End, Shift+Home, and you can Shift-Click an arbitrary range with the mouse; all these things can cause the same problem.