# IsSelected Binding in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I have in my Model (Class X) Boolean property: `IsSelected`, is linked to a `WPF DataGrid` as follows:

```
<DataGrid  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedXIndex,Mode=TwoWay}" 
           DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding ListX}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.RowStyle>
         <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
             <Setter Property="IsSelected" 
                     Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, 
                             UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
         </Style>
     </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

`ListX`- ObservableCollection

`IsSelecte`- Call to NotifyPropertyChange

It works great.

But when I have a lot of rows, that I need to scroll to see them, and I press the button "Select All" that runs the following function, he chooses me only some of the rows and not all: (Even though all the IsSelected on the list is **true**)

```
public void SelectAll()
{
    ListX.All(c => c.IsSelected = true);
}
```

I can not understand why this is happening?

Comment: Have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2068130/620360) from the Related section?

Comment: @LPL It did not help me, the answers there not successful. And I'm talking about the return data from viewModel to XMAL and that question is the opposite

Answer (score 16, accepted):

that's what helped me finally:

I put in the DataGrid:

```
VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"
```

Comment: If you need to use recycling mode (I do), another option is an attached behavior/codebehind that monitors the grid's OnSelectedCellsChanged event and reacts by updating the (de)selected VMs as indicated (will need to do the reverse too if two-way binding is desired).