# WPF ListView Delete Item IsSelected MVVM

Tags: wpf, listview, mvvm

I have a ListView that is bound to an Observable Collection of some object.. Selecting and item in the ListView displays a form. My business case is such when user toggles from one item to other in ListView  and if there are any unsaved changes, user should be prompted of Yes/No/Cancel. If the user clicks on No then, the selected item should be removed from the List.

I have a ViewModel for the ListViewItem and inside IsSelected property I am prompting the user. Now when I remove the item from the Observable Collection, the IsSelected = True for the next time that is getting selected, I am getting error..

> "Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute"..

Comment: you should really post some code. binding to your listbox, VM code and the snipped for the operation where the error is thrown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualizingStackPanel + MVVM + multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273659/virtualizingstackpanel-mvvm-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you're running into problems because your program is removing the currently-selected item from the collection at the same time it's selecting it.  Clicking on the item is changing `SelectedItem` for the `ListView`, and you're removing the item at the same time without setting a new value for `SelectedItem`.

What you probably want to do is create a property in the window's view model and bind the `ListView`'s `SelectedItem` property to it.  When the value of that property changes, you can prompt the user and then set `SelectedItem` to the appropriate value (i.e. to whatever the selected item should be after the currently-selected item is removed, or null if the collection's about to be empty) *before* you remove it from the underlying collection.

Comment: I m facing same issue, I understood your solution. I used same way but still facing same issue.