# How to bind multiple selection of listview to viewmodel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, selection

I am implementing a listview, and a button next to it. I have to be able that when i select multiple items in a listview, and then click on a button, then the selected items are put into a list. But my question is , how do i bind the selected items towards the viewmodel?
I changed my selectionmode to multiple. But then, do i just have to do:

```
SelectedItem={Binding path= selectedItems}
```

and then make in my viewmodel a property selectedItems, and it will set these items i have selected? Or what is the right solution to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VirtualizingStackPanel + MVVM + multiple selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273659/virtualizingstackpanel-mvvm-multiple-selection)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you can do is you can handle the Button_Click(...) in your code-behind. Then in that code-behind method you can create a List of selected items by iterating over the selected items of the listView.

Since it is allowed to access the ViewModel from the View you can now call a method on your ViewModel and pass the list of selected items as a parameter.

I'm not sure if this would also work with Bindings only, however it is not bad practice to use code-behind as well.

Example Code:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArguments arg)
{
  List<ListViewItem> mySelectedItems = new List<ListViewItem>();

  foreach(ListViewItem item in myListView.SelectedItems)
  {
    mySelectedItems.Add(item);
  }

  ViewModel.SomeMethod(mySelectedItems);
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is a minimalist example, XAML:

```
<DataTemplate
            x:Key="CarTemplate"
            DataType="{x:Type Car}">
</DataTemplate>

<ListView x:Name="myListView"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Cars}"
          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CarTemplate}">
</ListView>
```

CODE-BEHIND:

```
public void Button_Click(object sender, EventArguments arg)
    {
      List<Car> mySelectedItems = new List<Car>();

      foreach(Car item in myListView.SelectedItems)
      {
        mySelectedItems.Add(item);
      }

      ViewModel.SomeMethod(mySelectedItems);
    }
```

Comment: How do you parse ListViewItem to a particular object? because I can't do anything with listviewItem?

Comment: Well if your ListViewItem is of type MyType you can just use that: List<MyType> mySelectedItems = new List<MyType>(); foreach(MyType mytype in myListView.SelectedItems) ...

Comment: @Ruben - I have added a simple example. Good Luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but i also want to change the font, i do this:foreach (ListViewItem x in DropListView.SelectedItems)
            {
                x.FontStyle = FontStyles.Oblique;
            }

Comment: But he gives error, because SelectedItems is now not an object of ListViewItem?

Comment: @Ruben - Yes, because now you have your concrete class, like in my example: Car. What you can do is you can get your ListViewItem back. I will provide some code in a minute (need to look it up).

Comment: @Ruben - Try: ListViewItem item = myListView.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(myCar) as ListViewItem; Here "myCar" is the actual object you get from the list view. This will give you a ListViewItem whose FontStyle you can change.

Answer (score 51):

Like [Doctor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23058347/378115) has already pointed out, you can bind **SelectedItems** to XAML **CommandParameter**

After a lot of digging and googling, I have finally found a simple solution to this common issue.

To make it work you must **follow ALL the following rules**:

1. Following [Ed Ball's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336258/378115)', on you XAML command databinding, define **CommandParameter** property BEFORE **Command** property. This a very time-consuming bug.

   [image]
2. Make sure your **ICommand**'s **CanExecute** and **Execute** methods have a parameter of **object** type. This way you can prevent *silenced* cast exceptions that occurs whenever databinding **CommandParameter** type does not match your command method's parameter type.

   ```
   private bool OnDeleteSelectedItemsCanExecute(object SelectedItems)
   {
       // Your goes here
   }

   private bool OnDeleteSelectedItemsExecute(object SelectedItems)
   {
       // Your goes here
   }
   ```

For example, you can either send a listview/listbox's **SelectedItems** property to you **ICommand** methods or the listview/listbox it self. Great, isn't it?

Hope it prevents someone spending the huge amount of time I did to figure out how to receive **SelectedItems** as **CanExecute** parameter.

Comment: IMO this post should be marked as best answer - simple and leverages the API.  It's not obvious that attribute order can be significant, that's a nice find.

Comment: This approach does fit the OP question, but to have true data binding, please check my answer in this thread. It doesn't require button click or any event and pass as command parameter, it simply work like any other control that support data binding. Which i think, is a much better approach.

Comment: I got stuck on this one because `SelectedItems` is in `System.Windows.Controls`, which I don't reference from my ViewModels. The solution was to make the expected command parameter type be `System.Collections.IEnumerable`, and then `Cast<>` it.

Answer (score 24):

It's kind of tricky to do this Mutliple Selection in MVVM, because the `SelectedItems` property isn't a `Dependency Property`. However, there are some tricks you can use. I found this triology of blog posts that describe the matter in some details and provide some useful solutions.

- [Part I](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-i.html)
- [Part II](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-ii.html)
- [Part III](http://grokys.blogspot.com/2010/07/mvvm-and-multiple-selection-part-iii.html)

Hope this helps

Comment: problem is that those posts do not have entire code behind (download does not work), so it is currently kind of useles...

Comment: @etwas77 Third one still works (it's the only one you really need)

Comment: @ghord: it doesn't do two-way binding. e.g. if you set the SelectedItems it won't update the ListView

Answer (score 21):

If you are using System.Windows.Interactivity and Microsoft.Expression.Interactions already, here is a workaround without any other code/behaviour to mess around. If you need these, it can be download from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10801)

This workaround make use of interactivity event trigger and interactions set property mechanism in above assemblies.

**Additional namespace declaration in XAML**

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

**XAML:**

```
<ListView Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding ModelList}" DisplayMemberPath="Name"  Grid.Column="0">
  <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
      <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding Mode=OneWay}" PropertyName="SelectedItems" Value="{Binding Path=SelectedItems, ElementName=MyListView}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</ListView>
```

**View Model:**

```
public class ModelListViewModel
{
  public ObservableCollection<Model> ModelList { get; set; }
  public ObservableCollection<Model> SelectedModels { get; set; }

  public ModelListViewModel() {
    ModelList = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
    SelectedModels = new ObservableCollection<Model>();
  }

  public System.Collections.IList SelectedItems {
    get {
      return SelectedModels;
    }
    set {
      SelectedModels.Clear();
      foreach (Model model in value) {
        SelectedModels.Add(model);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In example above, your ViewModel will pick up the selected items whenever the selection on ListView changed.

Comment: The required packages for this solution are also available on nuget: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Blend.Interctivity.WPF.v4.0/1.0.2

Comment: While this worked for me, know that this essentially is a one-way binding. If I destroy my view but keep the VM alive, and then create a new instance of the view and binding it to that VM, the ListBox does not update selected items. I have to manually catch `Loaded` event of the `ListBox` and therein run a loop on my `SelectModels` property to add all those models to `SelectedItems` of the ListBox one by one.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately the SelectedItems is a read only not bindable property.

I found a lot of help from this article [How to Databind to a SelectedItems property in WPF](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2009/02/how-to-databind-to-selecteditems.html)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `Metro/WinRT` you may want to look at the [WinRTXXAMLToolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com) as it offers a bindable `SelectedItems` dependency property as one of its extensions.

Answer (score 3):

You can't bind, but you can send to Command as an CommandParameter.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation on Christian's post, I implemented similar code using the ListView.SelectionChanged event. Instead of calling a method on the ViewModel, I set a property called SelectedItems:

```
public void ListView_SelectionChanged( object s, SelectionChangedEventArgs e ) {
    List<Car> mySelectedItems = new List<Car>();

    foreach( Car item in myListView.SelectedItems )
        mySelectedItems.Add(item);

    ViewModel.SelectedItems = mySelectedItems;
}
```

This way, ViewModel.SelectedItems is available for any command you might have in your ViewModel *and* it can be used for data binding (if you turn it into an ObservableCollection).

Comment: This is not a good practice as MVVM really does not promote code behind unless no other solution around.

Answer (score 0):

I did a solution for this, to me this was simple enough.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfModel}" x:Name="ModelList"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel, Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ExecuteListBoxSelectionChange}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ModelList}">
                                    </i:InvokeCommandAction>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </ListBox>
```

Then in the viewmodel:

```
public ICommand ExecuteListBoxSelectionChange { get; private set; }
ExecuteListBoxSelectionChange = DelegatingCommand<ListBox>.For(ListBoxSelectionChnageEvent).AlwaysEnabled();
```

SelectedModels  is the list where I wanted the selection to be filled.

```
    private void ListBoxSelectionChnageEvent(ListBox modelListBox)
    {
        List<ModelInfo> tempModelInfo = new List<ModelInfo>();
         foreach(ModelInfo a in modelListBox.SelectedItems)
             tempModelInfo.Add(a);

         SelectedModels = tempModelInfo;
    }
```