# WPF DataGrid programmatic multiple row selection

Tags: wpf, select, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

Is there anything simpler than sample below ?  I do have observable collection ( "list" in the code )  bound to DataGrid lstLinks

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count ; i++)
{
    object rowItem = lstLinks.Items[i] ; 
    DataGridRow visualItem =  (DataGridRow)lstLinks.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(rowItem);
    if ( visualItem == null ) break;  
    if (list[i].Changed)
        visualItem.IsSelected = false;
    else
         visualItem.IsSelected = false; 

}
```

Comment: And it only works for visible rows.

Answer (score 9):

### Salam MicMit :)

Yeah, there is a more simple solution, you need just to add the items you want from your bound list to your DataGrid SelectedItems collection, see the code below: [Don't forget to mark as answer if this post solved your problem :)]

```
<Window x:Class="ProgGridSelection.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="OnWindowLoaded">
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid Name="empDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Height="200"/>
    <TextBox Name="empNameTextBox"/>
    <Button Content="Click" Click="OnSelectionButtonClick" />
</StackPanel>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public class Employee
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<Employee> _empCollection;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnWindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Generate test data
        _empCollection =
            new ObservableCollection<Employee>
                {
                    new Employee {Code = "E001", Name = "Mohammed A. Fadil"},
                    new Employee {Code = "E013", Name = "Ahmed Yousif"},
                    new Employee {Code = "E431", Name = "Jasmin Kamal"},
                    new Employee {Code = "E431", Name = "Zuhair Zein"},
                    new Employee {Code = "E431", Name = "Layla Abdullah"},
                };

        /* Set the Window.DataContext, alternatively you can set your
         * DataGrid DataContext property to the employees collection.
         * on the other hand, you you have to bind your DataGrid
         * DataContext property to the DataContext (see the XAML code)
         */
        DataContext = _empCollection;
    }

    private void OnSelectionButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* select the employee that his name matches the
         * name on the TextBox
         */
        var emp = (from i in _empCollection
                   where i.Name == empNameTextBox.Text.Trim()
                   select i).FirstOrDefault();

        /* Now, add it to your DataGrid SelectedItems collection to
         * add the item to the selected rows
         */
        if (emp != null)
            empDataGrid.SelectedItems.Add(emp);
    }
}
```

Comment: This Breaks the MVVM Pattern, and MVC,
But this wasn't stated in the question.

Comment: @TomerW. Yes, but this is another issue. I preferred to focus on the problem and make the solution as simple as possible.

Comment: possible... heck.. if you have asked me about 2 months ago, i would say 1. i am a winforms guy... 2. exactly like that :)

Answer (score 1):

MVVM Require more tender solution,
but it is MVVM and it is fully testable and easy to maintain.

Take a look here 
[Managing multiple selections with MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/803216/managing-multiple-selections-with-mvvm)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, this solution is better than hacking into the DataGrid control, and if you want to select only one row you can also use the following code:

```
myDataGrid.SelectedItem = item;
```

where the item is one of the items bound the DataGrid.

Comment: how exactly that do multi-selection?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `lstLinks` is a WPF `DataGrid`, this adds item at position `i` to the selected items:

```
lstLinks.SelectedItems.Add(lstLinks.Items[i]);
```

To unselect everything:

```
lstLinks.SelectedItems.Clear();
```