# How can I programatically select a listview item from within the viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a MVVM application with a `MainWindowViewModel` connected to a `MainWindow`view.
On the `MainWindow` view I have a `ComboBox` containing stock ticker symbols.

I have another viewmodel and view called `AllStockQuoteViewModel` connected to `AllStockQuoteView` which contains a list of stocks and their prices.

I want to be able to select an item from the `ComboBox` and have the item in the `AllStockQuoteView` selected and highlighted.  On my `MainWindowViewModel` I have saved the reference to the `AllStockQuoteViewModel` and use it to call a method to find the stock ticker symbol in the `ObservableCollection` bound to the `AllStockQuoteView`, but haven't found a way to programmatically select the item on the `AllStockQuoteView`.

I have a `SelectedQuote` property on the `AllStockQuoteViewModel` bound to the listview on the `AllStockQuoteView` and I can select one of the items and my `SelectedQuote` property is set fine.  If I set this programmatically in my `SelectQuote` method, it doesn't appear as if the item is selected in the view, although the item is passed back to the `MainWindowViewModel` and I can use it to populate the textblocks on `MainWindow` view.

I'd like to be able to show the item on the `AllStockQuoteView` as being selected via highlighting as if the user selected it.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Its very easy to implement

You need two things in your view model 
A List of your objects and a selected item property

```
        private CustomObject _selectedCustomObject;

        public ObservableCollection<CustomObject> CustomObjects
        {
            get
            {
                return new ObservableCollection<CustomObject>();
            }
        }

        public CustomObject SelectedCustomObject
        {
            get { return _selectedCustomObject; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedCustomObject== value)
                {
                    return;
                }

                _selectedCustomObject= value;
                PropertyChanged.Raise(this, x => x.SelectedCustomObject);
            }
        }
```

Then in your view you add your List/Combo control and bind to both properties.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CustomObjects}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCustomObject}">
```

Then all you need to do is set the viewmodel properties and the view will update.

Comment: The problem with the above code is that each time it retrieves the CustomObjects collection, it creates a new one destroying whatever was in it before...I end up with nothing to display...

Comment: Yeah, You can implement those two properties how you see fit. I used it for the sake of an example, you could return a private variable just like the selected item. (The original code I modified for this example, did a request from a model for an updated list from the data store instead of a static list). Your original question was mainly about the selected item. I failed to mention that whatever you assign to the selected item property must be in the list of object (reference match).

Answer (score 0):

First you have to think about your model and the whole MVVM approach, a good starting point is http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kashiffl/archive/2010/11/14/mvvm-technical-description.aspx.

After you can implement your functionality by different ways, one would be to implement something like the [Observer Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) or you try to use methods like [Notify Property-Changed-Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx).

Hope i was able to help,

Greetings

Comment: Thanks, I'll check these items out and evaluate my design.  But I still have the basic question of how can a MVVM viewmodel programmatically select an item in it's view?

Comment: Check this question out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803216/managing-multiple-selections-with-mvvm - i think it will help you solving your problem.