# How do I get a DataTrigger from a cell in a ListViewItem to select the row?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a DataTrigger defined in a CellTemplate for a row in a ListViewItem inside a ListView ...how do I get it to select the entire row it is part of?

Comment: I think you should be looking at ListView.SelectedItem to set row selection.  If you want to set the selection based on contents of your data, you should look at implementing an IsSelected property on your data rows, like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803216/managing-multiple-selections-with-mvvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't select a row in `DataTrigger`. Select it in your view model instead:

a) Define `IsSelected` property and change this property value, when condition, which `DataTrigger` is based on, becomes true:

```
public class DiabloIICharacter : ViewModelBase
{
    public String Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            if (name != value)
            {
                name = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    private String name;

    public Boolean IsBoss
    {
        get { return isBoss; }
        set
        {
            if (isBoss != value)
            {
                isBoss = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsBoss");

                if (isBoss)
                    // when a character becomes a boss, it becomes selected too
                    IsSelected = true;
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isBoss;

    public Boolean IsSelected
    {
        get { return isSelected; }
        set
        {
            if (isSelected != value)
            {
                isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
    }
    private Boolean isSelected;
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new[]
        {
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Diablo", IsBoss = true },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Oblivion Knight", IsBoss = false },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Blood Lord", IsBoss = false },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Andariel", IsBoss = true },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Baal", IsBoss = true },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Minion of Destruction", IsBoss = false },
            new DiabloIICharacter { Name = "Megademon", IsBoss = false },
        };
    }
}
```

b) Bind `ListViewItem.IsSelected` and `ViewModel.IsSelected` via `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" 
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <Grid>
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ListView.Resources>
                <DataTemplate x:Key="IsBossTemplate">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="50" Height="20" x:Name="IsBossMark"/>
                    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding IsBoss}">
                            <Setter TargetName="IsBossMark" Property="Fill" Value="DarkRed"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.Resources>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Character name"
                                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Is boss" 
                                    CellTemplate="{StaticResource IsBossTemplate}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Funnily enough, that's what I ended up doing - felt a little hack-ish at the time but I'm starting to see that this is actually the normal / recommended way to do it in WPF / MVVM from examples I'm seeing of similar problems

Comment: @blue18hutthutt: yes, it's true MVVM way. :) View model is a data, prepared to be displayed in the view. It is not a pure data.

Answer (score 1):

Just apply a Name to the ListView. like `<ListView Name="mylistView"... />` now you can just create a binding in your celltemplate like this
`{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=mylistView}` and you have your binding to the selecteditem

Comment: Wow, so simple and I didn't even think of that. Brain turns to mush at 4am