# Getting WPF ListView.SelectedItems in ViewModel

Tags: .net, wpf, listview, data-binding, mvvm

There are some posts discussing adding data-binding ability for `ListView.SelectedItems` with non-trivial amount of code. In my scenario I don't need to set it from the `ViewModel`, just getting selected items in order to perform action on them and it is triggered by command so push update is also not necessary.

Is there a simple solution (in terms of lines of code), maybe in code-behind? I am fine with code-behind as long as `View` and `ViewModel` don't need to reference each other. I think this is a more generic question: "*best practice for VM to get data from the View on-demand*", but I can't seem to find anything...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To get the `SelectedItems` only when a command is executed then use `CommandParameter` and pass in the `ListView.SelectedItems`.

```
<ListBox x:Name="listbox" ItemsSource="{Binding StringList}" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
<Button Command="{Binding GetListItemsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=listbox}" Content="GetSelectedListBoxItems"/>
```

Comment: `SelectedItems` (plural) does not support data-binding. See [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/803216/managing-multiple-selections-with-mvvm) and [this link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/edd335ea-e5e1-48e1-91a2-793d613f5cc3/). It doesn't work as `CommandParameter` either, I always get `null`, while using `SelectedItem` (singular) is fine.

Comment: @user986080 I didn't realize that `SelectedItems` did not support binding. I removed that from the answer. However the `CommandParameter` does work, I've tested it and was able to the list of selected items.

Comment: My XAML example shows a `ListBox` but I've also tested a `ListView` as well and was able to get the selected items from the command parameter.

Comment: I think I am hitting [this CommandParameter bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called) which is hassle to workaround. But ideally your answer is the right way to go.

Comment: Really thanks a lot for providing this CommandParamter solution. Worked great for me

Comment: What happens when `GetListItemsCommand` is a Command defined in the ViewModel? The first binding uses the ViewModel as the DataContext and the second binding to the parameter uses itself as a DataContext...

Comment: I don't remember where I saw this (someone else on StackOverflow) but CommadParameter must be defined before Command in your xaml for you to pass the SelectedItems as a parameter. It worked for me (Edit: oops sorry its also in one of the answers on this page)

Answer (score 11):

This can be achieved using Interaction triggers as below

1. You will need to add reference to

   Microsoft.Expression.Interactions
   System.Windows.Interactivity

Add below xmlns to your xaml

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression//2010/interactivity"
xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
```

Add code below just inside your GridView tag

```
<GridView x:Name="GridName">
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
   <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
       <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Datacontext.SelectionChangedCommand, ElementName=YourUserControlName}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItems, ElementName=GridName}" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Code Inside ViewModel declare property below

```
public DelegateCommand<object> SelectionChangedCommand {get;set;}
```

within constructor of Viewmodel initialize Command as below

```
SelectionChangedCommand = new DelegateCommand<object> (items => {
   var itemList = (items as ObservableCollection<object>).Cast<YourDto>().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think it's correct condition to consider that '***View and ViewModel don't need to know each other***'; *In MVVM view always know about ViewModel.*

I have also come across this kind of situation where I had to access ViewModel in view's code behind and then populate some data(like selected items), this becomes necessary while using 3'rd party controls like ListView, DataGrid etc.

If directly binding the VM property is not possible then I would listen to ListViw.SelectionChanged event and then update my ViewModels SelectedItems property in that event.

**Update:**

To enable VM pull data from view, You can expose an interface on the View that handles View-specific functionality and ViewModel will have reference of your View through that interface; Using an interface still keeps the View and ViewModel largely decoupled but I genrally don't prefer this.

[MVVM, providing the Association of View to ViewModel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davihard/archive/2010/05/10/repost-mvvm-providing-the-association-of-view-to-viewmodel.aspx)

I would still prefer the approch of handling the event in View and keep the VM updated(with the selected items), this way VM don't need to worry about pulling the data before performing any operation, it just needs to use the data available(as that will always be updated one).

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. By not knowing each other I mean one does not reference the other.
Also registering to `SelectionChanged` event is not exactly necessary as the ViewModel only needs to get selected items when a command is being executed. It's more like "How can VM pull data from the View on demand".

Answer (score 3):

I can assure you: **SelectedItems** is indeed bindable as a XAML **CommandParameter**

After a lot of digging and googling, I have finally found a simple solution to this common issue.

To make it work you must **follow ALL the following rules**:

1. Following [Ed Ball's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/336258/378115)', on you XAML command databinding, define **CommandParameter** property BEFORE **Command** property. This a very time-consuming bug.
2. Make sure your **ICommand**'s **CanExecute** and **Execute** methods have a parameter of **object** type. This way you can prevent *silenced* cast exceptions that occurs whenever databinding **CommandParameter** type does not match your command method's parameter type.

   ```
   private bool OnDeleteSelectedItemsCanExecute(object SelectedItems)  
   {
       // Your goes heres
   }

   private bool OnDeleteSelectedItemsExecute(object SelectedItems)  
   {
       // Your goes heres
   }
   ```

For example, you can either send a listview/listbox's **SelectedItems** property to you **ICommand** methods or the listview/listbox it self. Great, isn't it?

Hope it prevents someone spending the huge amount of time I did to figure out how to receive **SelectedItems** as **CanExecute** parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the other answers helped me (using `SelectedItems` as `CommandParameter` was always `null`), here is a solution for Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps. It works using `Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity` and `Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core`.

Here's the View:

```
<ListView x:Name="ItemsList">
    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
         <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="SelectionChanged">
             <Core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.SelectedItemsChanged}" />
         </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <!-- content etc. -->
</ListView>
```

Here's the ViewModel (`RelayCommand` is a class from MVVM Light):

```
private List<YourType> _selectedItems = new List<YourType>();

private RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> _selectedItemsChanged;
public RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs> SelectedItemsChanged
{
    get
    {
        if (_selectedItemsChanged == null)
            _selectedItemsChanged = new RelayCommand<SelectionChangedEventArgs>((selectionChangedArgs) =>
            {
                // add a guard here to immediatelly return if you are modifying the original collection from code

                foreach (var item in selectionChangedArgs.AddedItems)
                    _selectedItems.Add((YourType)item);

                foreach (var item in selectionChangedArgs.RemovedItems)
                    _selectedItems.Remove((YourType)item);
            });
        return _selectedItemsChanged;
    }
}
```

Beware that if you are going to remove items from the original collection after the selection is completed (user pushes a button etc.), it will also remove the items from your `_selectedItems` list! If you do this in a foreach loop, you'll get an `InvalidOperationException`. To avoid this, simply add a guard in the marked place like:

```
if (_deletingItems)
    return;
```

and then in the method where you for example remove the items, do this:

```
_deletingItems = true;
foreach (var item in _selectedItems)
    YourOriginalCollection.Remove(item);
_deletingItems = false;
```