# How to add up a column of a ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying display the total value of the items selected, the selected items are in a ListView. The values of item appear in the list but I want the total value of items to display inside a textbox. My code is below:

**Basket.xaml**

```
       private static ObservableCollection<Menu.PassedData> passedData = new ObservableCollection<Menu.PassedData>();

 private double totalValue;
        public double TotalValue
        {
            get { return totalValue; }
            set
            {
                totalValue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
            }
        }

  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;

    if (data != null) //If data is not 0 
    {
        PassedData.Add(data); //Increment data in list view

        double tempTotalValue = 0;
        foreach (var record in PassedData)
        {
            tempTotalValue = tempTotalValue + record.Value;
        }
        TotalValue = tempTotalValue;
    }
}


    }
```

**The list in which the values are stored(Basket.xaml)**

```
 <ListBox x:Name="listBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="265" Margin="278,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112">
        <ListView x:Name="PriceView" ItemsSource="{Binding PassedData}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <!--<TextBox Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True" /> !-->
                        <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </ListBox>
```

So basically add up the Value column in listview and display it in a textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to achieve this. Using your code you may for example:
In your `Basket.xaml.cs` add `TotalValue` property:

```
private double totalValue;
public double TotalValue
{
    get { return totalValue; }
    set
    {
        totalValue = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("TotalValue");
    }
}
```

And then in your `OnNavigatedTo` method you can just iterate through all elements of your list to get total value:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    Menu.PassedData data = e.Parameter as Menu.PassedData;

    if (data != null) //If data is not 0 
    {
        PassedData.Add(data); //Increment data in list view

        double tempTotalValue = 0;
        foreach (var record in PassedData)
        {
            tempTotalValue = tempTotalValue + record.Value;
        }
        TotalValue = tempTotalValue;
    }
}
```

And then just bind this value to lets say `Textblock` in your view `Basket.xaml`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding TotalValue}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have implemented your answer but when I run the app the total textblock stays static-only displays 0 no matter how many items I add an item. The question is updatated.

Comment: Does your `Basket` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: In order to make your `OnPropertyChanged` method work you have to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, like this: `public sealed partial class Basket : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged`

Answer (score 0):

Something like [Getting WPF ListView.SelectedItems in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964910/getting-wpf-listview-selecteditems-in-viewmodel) could be useful. Then in your command use linq to get a sum of all the values and set some property (bound) with this value.