# MVVM Saving in database using ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, icommand

I have dialog for getting some basic information for saving these in the database on click of a save button.
These basic information will be stored in the ViewModel via binding. I handle the database via Entity Framework and so via a DataContext.

```
private Command.MonitoringTaskCommand objSaveButtonCommand =
    new Command.MonitoringTaskCommand(
        new Action<DataModel.MonitoringTask>(x => {
            DataModel.MonitorContext context = new DataModel.MonitorContext();
            context.MonitoringTasks.Add(x);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }),
        new Func<bool>(() => {
            Debug.WriteLine("Todo: Validate data... ");
            return true;
        }));
```

I stuck at the save execution.

- How can I pass the data to the Command?

I know there is the CommandParameter on XAML level, but the data is stored in the ViewModel and can be different from that one in the XAML level.

Comment: XAML view elements should be data bound your viewmodel's properties (and updating these if required). Also consider using data access layer for accessing your EF context. Command parameter is the way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371253/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-as-a-commandparameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data pass from the binding of your command so where your bindings are use CommandParameter to bind your object

Check this tutorial

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e06010/wpf-icommand-in-mvvm/