# C# WPF ICommand interface not works

Tags: c#, wpf, icommand

I have problem with ICommand interface. My button doesn't work properly. I want to enable it when name and id are filled. It seems that name and id not have a value. At least I think that. I have tried create new object of MainWindow and refer to field text but it didnt't work

XAML

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:m="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <m:Repository x:Key="P"/>
    <mv:ViewM x:Key="C"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Border CornerRadius="23" Background="Black" Padding="10">
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource C}}">

        <TextBlock Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Main" Padding="0,5,0,0"/>
        <Separator Margin="0,10,0,0"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False" Text="{Binding ID, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,5,0,0" Margin="0,4,0,0" MaxLength="20"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="200" IsReadOnly="False" Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,5,0,0" Margin="0,4,0,0" MaxLength="20"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="30" Width="200" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Full, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextAlignment="Center" Padding="0,5,0,0" Margin="0,4,0,0" MaxLength="20"/>
        <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="20" Width="100" Content="CHuj" Margin="0,20,0,0"
                 Command="{Binding com}" CommandParameter="{Binding Repo, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>

</Border>
```

ICommand

```
public class Icom : ICommand
{

    public ViewM VieM { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;


    public Icom(ViewM view)
    {
        this.VieM = view;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Repository R = (Repository)parameter;
        if (R != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(R.Name) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(R.ID)))
                return false;

            return true;
        }

       return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        VieM.Wy();
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public class Repository : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _id;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set { _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    private string _full;

    public string Full
    {
        get { return Name + " " + ID; }
        set { _full = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    public Repository()
    {
        this.Name = "";
        this.ID = "";
    }


    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
 public class ViewM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string _id;

    public string ID
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            Repo = new Repository()
            {
                Full = this.Full,
                Name = this.Name,
                ID = this.ID
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("ID");
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            Repo = new Repository()
            {
                Full = this.Full,
                Name = this.Name,
                ID = this.ID
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    private string _full;

    public string Full
    {
        get { return Name + " " + ID; }
        set
        {
            _full = value;
            Repo = new Repository()
            {
                Full = this.Full,
                Name = this.Name,
                ID = this.ID                 
            };
            OnPropertyChanged("Full");
        }

    }

    private Repository _repo;

    public Repository Repo
    {
        get { return _repo; }
        set
        {
            _repo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Repo");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public Icom com { get; set; }

    public ViewM()
    {
        this.com = new Icom(this);
    }

    public void Wy()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Text");
    }
}
```

Comment: [To ensure that your events are being raised properly you should raise the CanExecuteChanged event when the \[...\] value changes.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12371891/7598462)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable as a CommandParameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371253/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-as-a-commandparameter)

Answer (score 1):

Your button needs to reevaluate whether or not it can be executed after your values change.

The `CommandManager` only pays attention to certain conditions in determining when the command target has changed, such as change in keyboard focus. In situations where the `CommandManager` does not sufficiently determine a change in conditions that cause a command to not be able to execute, the 
 [CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested(v=vs.110).aspx) can be called to force the `CommandManager` to raise the `RequerySuggested` event.

Answer (score 0):

I got it

```
public class Icom : ICommand
{

    public ViewM VieM { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
    }

    public Icom(ViewM view)
    {
        this.VieM = view;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        Repository R = (Repository)parameter;
        if (R != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(R.ID) || (string.IsNullOrEmpty(R.Name)))
                return false;

            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        VieM.Wy();
    }
}
```

And in ViewM

```
 private Repository _repo;

    public Repository Repo
    {
        get { return _repo; }
        set
        {
            _repo = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Repo");
            com.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```