# Windows Phone - Binding TextBox or other control to CommandParameter of Button

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, icommand

I'm making my first steps into using Commands (by implementing the `ICommand` interface) in my Windows Phone applications. Now I've run into a problem I can't seem to figure out. I'm binding a control, in this case it's a textbox, to the `CommandParameter` property of a `Button`:

```
<Button x:Name="BTN_Search"
        Style="{StaticResource ButtonNoPressedStyle}"
        BorderThickness="0"
        ccontrols:TiltEffect.IsTiltEnabled="True"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Height="85"
        Margin="0,0,0,-2"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=TB_Search}"
        Command="{Binding SearchTermCommand}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Images/searchbtn.png" />
        </Button.Background>
</Button>
```

When the application starts and the viewmodel is instantiated, the `CanExecute` method gets fired twice in a row.

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            var textbox = parameter as TextBox;
            if ((textbox.DataContext as MainPageViewmodel).SearchTerm == null)
            {
                (textbox.DataContext as MainPageViewmodel).SearchTerm = "";
                return true;
            }
            else if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textbox.Text)) return false;
            else if (textbox.Text.Any(Char.IsDigit)) return false;
            else if (textbox.Text.Length < 4) return false;
            else if (_commandExecuting) return false;
            else
            {
                var bindingExpression = textbox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
                bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The first time the parameter is `null` and the second time it contains the textbox. Because of this behavior I have to make it so that these first two times, the `CanExecute` method returns true, else the button will be disabled.

I've read some other topics that it may have to do with `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`, but I'm not so sure of that either.
This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called)
has some answers regarding this issue, but the answers don't fit my needs, since most solutions are for WPF (using the `CommandManager`, or a `IMultiValueConverter`) and others don't seem to work.

Is there any solution to make sure `CanExecute` only fires once, or what's the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: It seems like an abuse of the ICommand pattern to update a binding expression inside the test for "CanExecute".  Why would you need to do that?

Comment: Because I had this idea of updating only when needed (when all requirements were met). After looking into this, I figured I could just add INotifyPropertyChanged to the property in question. Thank you for bringing this to my attention. But I'd still like to know why this is happening.

Comment: I don't know why exactly, but this guess makes sense to me:  the first check is when the command object is first constructed; and the second check is when the CommandParameter is bound (ie, the TB_Search element is loaded).

Comment: So that means each control or property tied to the command, triggers RaiseCanExecuteChanged() when it has loaded or updated?

Comment: Good questions, I really don't know ... I do from experience that property changes via NotifyPropertyChanged *do not* trigger it.  Dependency property changes?  Changes to the visual tree?  No idea ...

Comment: Hmmm, when I bind the SearchTerm property (a string) directly to the CommandParameter and I set this property in the constructor of my viewmodel, CanExecute also gets fired twice. First null and then with the value. It doesn't matter if I implement INotifyPropertyChanged though... am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

I think your textbox is not initialized when command parameter is bounded first time. Try to bind textbox with viewmodel parameter (parameter must be [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/cc221408%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) or your viewmodel must implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx) interface) with twoway mode then pass this parameter to command parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This answer doesn't provide any definite conclusions, but after I tested with various bindings on the `CommandParameter` and looking at the [information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft for the ICommand interface and the associated `CanExecuteChanged` event, I have to conclude that it has to do with either one of the following, which McGarnagle already suggested:

- **Changes to the visual tree.**
- **Changes to a dependency property/object.**

This is plausible because the docs say the following: "Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command should execute."

What I noticed:

- When binding any property of the Viewmodel, CanExecute only gets fired **once** at startup. The parameter is `null`.
- When binding any other element **or** a property of this element, `CanExecute` gets fired **twice** at startup. The parameter is `null` the first time and the second time it contains either the element or the property of the specified element.
- When binding the Button itself `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}`, CanExecute gets fired **once** at startup and the parameter contains the Button element.

As I said before, this doesn't answer anything, but I thought providing some additional info on this matter wouldn't hurt. If someone finds a definitive answer, providing the *why* of this behavior, I would certainly appreciate that.

Anyway, I used the first scenario in my own app and restructered the logic so now it's working as I originally intended.