# Prism DelegateCommand's CanExecute getting null parameter after RaiseCanExecuteChanged

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, prism

I'm trying to write a `ListView`, where for each item there is a button bound to a `DelegateCommand`. I want this command's `CanExecute` to be based on a boolean property of an item. `ItemSource` is an `ObservableCollection` and I'm populating it using an `async` method. The problem is that when `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` is fired, `CanExecute` receives `null` as parameter.After that, when I use another UI bound command to `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()`, the method behaves properly.

Here's part of the view:

```
<ListView x:Name="root" ItemsSource="{Binding olVersions}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="true" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=sFullName}" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                <Button Grid.Column="1" Content="Run" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.cRunVersionCommand}"></Button>
                <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Download" CommandParameter="{Binding}" Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.cDownloadVersionCommand}"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Here's the ViewModel:

```
public class VersionsTabViewModel : BindableBase
{

    public ObservableCollection<CVersion> olVersions { get; private set; }

    public DelegateCommand<CVersion> cRunVersionCommand { get; private set; }
    public DelegateCommand<CVersion> cDownloadVersionCommand { get; private set; }

    private IVersionManager c_version_manager;

    public VersionsTabViewModel(IVersionManager cVersionManager)
    {
        olVersions = new ObservableCollection<CVersion>();
        cRunVersionCommand = new DelegateCommand<CVersion>(v_try_run_version, b_can_run);
        cDownloadVersionCommand = new DelegateCommand<CVersion>(v_try_download_version);
        c_version_manager = cVersionManager;
        v_read_available_versions();
    }

    private async void v_read_available_versions()
    {
        List<CVersion> l_versions = await c_version_manager.lGetVersions();
        List<CVersion> l_versions_sorted = l_versions.OrderByDescending(cVersion => cVersion.cSemanticVersion).ToList();
        olVersions.Clear();
        olVersions.AddRange(l_versions_sorted);

        cRunVersionCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private void v_try_run_version(CVersion cVersionToRun)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Run {cVersionToRun.sFullName}", "Run"); //TODO
    }

    private void v_try_download_version(CVersion cVersionToDownload)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Download {cVersionToDownload.sFullName}", "Download"); //TODO
        cRunVersionCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private bool b_can_run(CVersion cVersion)
    {
        return cVersion?.bIsInstalled ?? false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this is a general issue with command bindings, there is a related question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called). In order to make it work in your case, you have to change your `ElementName` binding to `root` for the `Command` property from

```xaml
Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.cRunVersionCommand}"
```

to a relative source binding to the parent `ListView` control like this.

```
Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}, Path=DataContext.cRunVersionCommand}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It solved it. I've seen the answer you linked earlier today, but it somehow didn't click for me then.

Comment: The solution that solved this problem for me can be found in the linked related question, specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38961061/1073822