# Binding of command parameter with Element value of a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, commandparameter

Iam Trying to Bind "Description" column value of dataGrid to command parameter of a button inside same grid row but, Binding not working properly.
code:-

```
   <DataGrid x:Name="devicelist" Background="SkyBlue" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DeviceList}" SelectionChanged="devicelist_SelectionChanged"  >
 <DataGrid.Columns>  
                <!--Description-->
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Descrition" Width="*"  IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path=Description}">
                </DataGridTextColumn>                         
                          
                <!--testcaseSelection button-->
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="TestCases" Width="*" >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type Window}}, 
                             Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.SelectTestCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Description}" >TestCases</Button>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
 </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

the command that i have binded is working properly and getting called also.

Comment: Please clarify: "Binding not working properly" - how exactly? What do you expect to see and what do you get instead?

Comment: i have a list(deviceList) which i have binded to datagrid. this Description coloumn and testcase button are part of same row. and initialy when dataGrid is Loading and the value getting passed as Command Parameter is NULL. Even though description column is populating with data. 
note:- and if iam clicking several time on the Row then automatically its Getting correct value. So can you tell me what could be the problem. and if the way Iam binding command and command parameter  is correct.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WPF CommandParameter is NULL first time CanExecute is called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335849/wpf-commandparameter-is-null-first-time-canexecute-is-called)

Comment: no this is not working. please suggest some other solution.

Answer (score -1):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4047384/361177), try to declare the `CommandParameter` before the `Command`:

```
<Button CommandParameter="{Binding Path=Description}"
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType= {x:Type Window}}, 
                          Path=DataContext.CurrentViewModel.SelectTestCommand}"
        Content="TestCases" />
```

Comment: this approach is not working, can you suggest something else